# Взять переменные из форматированной строки Python

Tags: python, строки, format

Есть общий формат строки `'1.{minor:03d}.{number:03d}'`. Как проще всего, желательно без регулярок, получить переменные minor и number из строки, например `1.002.003`? при чем, формат может поменяться, он прописывается в конфиге. Так что разбиение на список не совсем подходящий вариант.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте модуль `parse` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse)

> `parse()` is the opposite of `format()`

```
from parse import *

fmt = '1.{minor:03d}.{number:03d}' # Формат строки из конфига

data = '1.005.009' # Данные

t = parse(fmt, data)


print(t)
```